# Importing submodule using custom importer contains "<module>" in find_module fullname parameter

Tags: c#, python, import, hook, ironpython

Currently I'm working on a custom importer for Ironpython, which should add an abstraction layer for writing custom importer. The abstraction layer is an IronPython module, which bases on [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302) and the IronPython `zipimporter` module. The architecture looks like this:

[image: Architexture]

For testing my importer code, I've written a simple test package with modules, which looks like this:

```
/Math/
    __init__.py
    /MathImpl/
             __init__.py
             __Math2__.py
```

/Math/__init__.py:

```
print ('Import: /Math/__init__.py')
```

/Math/MathImpl/__init__.py:

```
# Sample math package
print ('Begin import /Math/MathImpl/__init__.py')
import Math2
print ('End import /Math/MathImpl/__init__.py: ' + str(Math2.add(1, 2)))
```

/Math/MathImpl/Math2.py:

```
# Add two values
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
print ('Import Math2.py!')
```

If i try to import `MathImpl` like this in a script: `import Math.MathImpl`

My `genericimporter` get's called and searchs for some module/package in the `find_module` method. Which returns an instance of the importer if found, else not:

```
public object find_module(CodeContext/*!*/ context, string fullname, params object[] args)
{
    // Set module
    if (fullname.Contains("<module>"))
    {
        throw new Exception("Why, why does fullname contains <module>?");
    }

    // Find resolver
    foreach (var resolver in Host.Resolver)
    {
        var res = resolver.GetModuleInformation(fullname);

        // If this script could be resolved by some resolver
        if (res != ResolvedType.None)
        {
            this.resolver = resolver;
            return this;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If `find_module` is called the first time,`fullname` contains `Math`, which is ok, because `Math` should be imported first. The second time `find_module` is called, `Math.MathImpl` should be imported, the problem here is, that `fullname` has now the value `<module>.MathImpl`, instead of `Math.MathImpl`.

My idea was, that the module name (`__name__`) is not set correctly when `Math` was imported, but i set this in any case when importing the module in `load_module`:

```
public object load_module(CodeContext/*!*/ context, string fullname)
{
    string code = null;
    GenericModuleCodeType moduleType;
    bool ispackage = false;
    string modpath = null;
    PythonModule mod;
    PythonDictionary dict = null;

    // Go through available import types by search-order
    foreach (var order in _search_order)
    {
        string tempCode = this.resolver.GetScriptSource(fullname + order.Key);

        if (tempCode != null)
        {
            moduleType = order.Value;
            code = tempCode;
            modpath = fullname + order.Key;

            Console.WriteLine("     IMPORT: " + modpath);

            if ((order.Value & GenericModuleCodeType.Package) == GenericModuleCodeType.Package)
            {
                ispackage = true;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    // of no code was loaded
    if (code == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var scriptCode = context.ModuleContext.Context.CompileSourceCode
        (
            new SourceUnit(context.LanguageContext, new SourceStringContentProvider(code), modpath, SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect),
            new IronPython.Compiler.PythonCompilerOptions() { },
            ErrorSink.Default
        );

    // initialize module
    mod = context.ModuleContext.Context.InitializeModule(modpath, context.ModuleContext, scriptCode, ModuleOptions.None);

    dict = mod.Get__dict__();

    // Set values before execute script
    dict.Add("__name__", fullname);
    dict.Add("__loader__", this);
    dict.Add("__package__", null);

    if (ispackage)
    {
        // Add path
        string subname = GetSubName(fullname);
        string fullpath = string.Format(fullname.Replace(".", "/"));

        List pkgpath = PythonOps.MakeList(fullpath);
        dict.Add("__path__", pkgpath);
    }
    else
    {
        StringBuilder packageName = new StringBuilder();
        string[] packageParts = fullname.Split(new char[] { '/' });
        for (int i = 0; i < packageParts.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                packageName.Append(".");
            }

            packageName.Append(packageParts[i]);
        }

        dict["__package__"] = packageName.ToString();
    }

    var scope = context.ModuleContext.GlobalScope;
    scriptCode.Run(scope);

    return mod;
}
```

I hope some one has an idea, why this happens. A few line which also may cause the problem are:

```
var scriptCode = context.ModuleContext.Context.CompileSourceCode
    (
       new SourceUnit(context.LanguageContext, new SourceStringContentProvider(code), modpath, SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect),
            new IronPython.Compiler.PythonCompilerOptions() { },
            ErrorSink.Default
     );
```

and

```
mod = context.ModuleContext.Context.InitializeModule(modpath, context.ModuleContext, scriptCode, ModuleOptions.None);
```

Because i don't know, whether creating a module this way is completly correct.

The problem can be reproduced downloading this project/branch: https://github.com/simplicbe/Simplic.Dlr/tree/f_res_noid and starting `Sample.ImportResolver`. An exception in `find_module` will be raised.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved. `Modpath` what not allowed to contains `/`. In general only chars were allowed, which also can be in a file-name.

Maybe this is helpful for someone else...